# How can I delete all the partitions and start afresh?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Owing to bad planning and lack of foresight, I messed up primary/logical partitions on my new 1TB HDD.

I need a dual boot Ubuntu and Windows, and one 100gb unallocated space just sits there in the middle.

I was thinking of merging it with the other unallocated space and install Windows on a logical partition, while Ubuntu remains on primary (is that even a good approach? )

Following is my GParted current view,is it possible to delete everything on the hard drive, all the partitions and start afresh by creating partitions from the beginning?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then you need to reinstall

Comment: I am fine with that. Do you mean I should put in the usb stick, boot in the live mode, and it will give me an option to wipe it all away?

Comment: I believe windows likes to be on a primary partition

Comment: Boot from the Ubuntu installer, open GParted and delete all partitions. Then you can start anew...

Comment: Why not just create another partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind to reinstall, I propose to reinstall instead of dealing with Gparted and all those partitions.

- Boot into Ubuntu Installation media. This can be either CD or USB
  stick.
- Start the installation. Proceed to Step 4 and choose "Something
  else":

  [image: Step 4 — Something else]
- You will see your disk as `/dev/sda`
- Click "New Partition Table..." You will see that you have free space
  on your disk now:

  [image: free space]
- Create partition for swap if you want to use it(recommended)
- Select free space and click <kbd>+</kbd> and set parameters
- Create partition for `/`
- Select free space and click <kbd>+</kbd> and set parameters
- Repeat the same steps as many times as you need partitions

Then move on and complete your installation

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on Dual Booting Windows and Ubuntu here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

It is recommended that you first install Windows and then Ubuntu.

Also, Ubuntu gives you an option to create a new partition table, when you install.

You can also find detailed installation instruction here: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html