# Need help formatting disk for 23.10

Tags: partitioning, java

Yesterday I upgraded to 23.10. Bad luck with a power failure near the end of the process.

Things looked pretty good as Ubuntu came up. Just to be sure I tried the system updater.
It said I was up to date. I also tried sudo apt autoremove. There was a list of files
which were not needed so I did the cleanup. (The final stage of removing unused files
wasn't reached because of the power failure.)
A repeat of autoremove showed all was well.

Then I noticed my Java program which deals with Hebrew wouldn't accept Hebrew characters. English was fine, but no Hebrew.
I went into the browser and there Hebrew worked with no problems. I checked the keyboard language, which was missing some parts, so I updated it. No change whatsoever.

I thought maybe Java was broken, so I put in the latest version. No change.
I also noticed my Netbeans IDE also wouldn't accept Hebrew. The IDE uses Java so it wasn't a total surprise. Again, I installed the latest version of the IDE. Again no change. I had run out of ideas so I decided to format my Linux partition (where my /home partition was separate and it is vitally important that there be zero changes on it).

In the past Sometimes I would have problems where I would just reformat the Linux partition and leave /home untouched, so I knew it works.

I put 23.10 on a disk on key and proceeded to try to format and overwrite the Linux partition. To my amazement the installer won't let me continue and I have no idea why.
Notice in the image below that Next is grayed out.

Edited with more data added....

After thinking about my options, I decided to try to make a USB for 20.03, go back to 20.03 and then upgrade again. I would again request to format the linux partition, in order to start with a clean slate.

I brought up the USB copy and asked for Install Ubuntu. It looked like my request was being ignored. I looked closely and it would start the process and then silently stop after about 1 sec. What was going on?? The only explanation which made any sense was it noticed that I was trying to go backwards and just stopped without calling me a total idiot. I don't know if this is a feature or a bug, so I'll call it a feature-bug.

Now suddenly what I asked above also made sense. I had asked to overwrite 23.10 with 23.10. No change here, so it can't go on wards. A feature-bug. (I did ask to format the linux partition, but it apparently missed that clue.)

Having a power failure while upgrading shouldn't be a very rare event. Rare yes, very rare no. There is yet another possible problem which I will add. I rather enjoy mahjongg, and it is much degraded in 23.10. I wouldn't go back to a previous version for a game, but it could be a much bigger problem for someone who loves it. In any case, the bottom line is, there can be reasons for wanting to go back.

In my case the most crucial part is not to lose my /home partition. So my only choice is the manual choice where I can leave the existing partition in place and not change my /home partition. The feature-bug which I happened upon is a real problem.

The only possible solution I can think of is to go to 22.04 LTS. Presumably that is permissible. Then I could return to 23.04 or 23.10 depending upon how much I value mahjongg. Since I didn't notice any visible improvements, I might tend to 23.04.

I have to do something soon, since I can't enter Hebrew characters into a java program I wrote. Likewise I can't change the program with the IDE because the IDE (which also uses java) won't accept Hebrew characters.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since my only real choice was to return to 22.04 LTS, I did that. The partitioning was a bit different. I started out as shown the question and after I hit the "Next" button the LTS version told me that I needed an efi partition. This what I originally did, but after 3+ years, I forgot. I was pleased with the installer that instead of just refusing, it told me exactly what my error was, and if I failed to correct it I would be proceeding at my own risk. Beautiful! I could have proceeded if I really wanted to. It was MY choice and not something hard wired.

I decided that between 23.04 and 23.10, I preferred 23.04. It had served me well and Mahjongg wasn't broken. So I put in the disk on key and again it refused to install! The reason seems to be that there is a hard wired decision not to allow installation after some given date. Why allow me to download it if I can't do anything with it? I much nicer solution would be to tell me that the software is now out of date and I load it at my own risk. (In fact it is still supposed to be supported as 1 year has not yet passed.)

So my only choice was to let LTS upgrade itself. I expected that it would go to 23.10, but instead it went to 23.04. Unbelievable, what was forbidden in the disk on key case, was the choice of the upgrade case.

The experience has taught me that I was wrong with the reason I couldn't go forward with the grayed out Next button. I don't know what the reason is. Using a disk on key for the LTS, noted the problem with the efi partition AFTER I hit the Next button.

In any case, I just wanted to document everything in case someone else needs to go back from 23.10 to 23.04. The attached image shows the correct values.

[image: partitioning]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score -1):

WARNING: BACKUP or DATA LOSS will occur -> if you really want to start with a clean ubuntu installation and you really don't have data to loose, then you need to boot with a live cd to delete or format your partitions and then head over to install. I would suggest https://gparted.org/livecd.php . Maybe the ubuntu installation dvd can do this as well so have a reading here [How can I delete all the partitions and start afresh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642212/how-can-i-delete-all-the-partitions-and-start-afresh)

Comment: This is what I used to set up the partitions in the first place. Now that I already have them, I just want to format the linux partition and leave the /home partition untouched. (I made the partitions some years ago.) In fact I used the same partitions in the past when I had problems with the linux OS. I would reinstall linux on the / partition and leave /home untouched. Now the process won't go to completion. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll continue to think about it.

Comment: I do not quite see how this answers the question that was asked. The question is about one step of the install process. Are you suggesting that the OP try some different install method?